# How do I 'convert' letters to numbers?

Tags: cobol

I'm writing a program that converts regular bank account numbers to IBAN numbers. Part of this process means I need to convert the letters (in fields like Bank-ID, Branch-ID and ISO-Country-CODE) into the numbers corresponding with their positions in the alphabet + 9. So A=10, B=11, Z=35.

So basically, the following Bank-ID: "LOYD" would become "21243413".

I need to put these numbers in a string later so I make calculations with it.

Now, if the input bank-ID would always be of equal length and always letters, I'd put this among the the rest of my working storage:

```
LETTERS    PIC X(36) VALUE '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.
```

And then I'd write this:

```
INITIALIZE BANK-CODE-NR
           PERFORM VARYING LOOP-COUNTR FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
                           LOOP-COUNTR > 4
           INSPECT         LETTERS
           TALLYING        BANK-CODE-NR(LOOP-COUNTER)  FOR
                           CHARACTERS BEFORE INITIAL BANK-CD IN
                           COPYBOOK(LOOP-COUNTR:1)
           END-PERFORM
```

But in this case, the bank ID may be four positions long, **or even longer**. Plus, I'm working with PIC N fields, which means the INSPECT doesn't work.

**EDITED FOR EXTRA INFO**

I'm working with a copybook that has nationals in it.
It is structured as follows:

```
     01 Input-IBAN.
          05 COUNTRY-CODE               PIC N(02).
          05 BANK-ID                    PIC N(10).
          05 BRANCH-ID                  PIC N(10).
          05 ACCOUNT-NR                 PIC N(28). 
          05 Output-IBAN                PIC N(34).
```

It's a called program.

Comment: You're going to need to show the definitions again. Are they still PIC N fields?

Comment: You can do it without any loops at all.

Comment: Yes they are still PIC N fields. I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. Q36201076.
AUTHOR. Magoo.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 LETTERS.
   03 LETTER-STRING                   PIC X(36) VALUE
                     "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".
   03 FILLER REDEFINES LETTER-STRING.
      05 LETTER-CHARACTER             PIC X(01) OCCURS 36.

01 BANK-CODE.
   03 BANK-CODE-CHARACTER             PIC X(01) OCCURS 4.

01 BANK-CODE-CONVERTED.
   03 BANK-CODE-NUMBER                PIC 9(02) OCCURS 4.

01 wORK-VARIABLES.
   03 LETTER-INDEX                    PIC 9(02).
   03 BANK-INDEX                      PIC 9(01).
   03 REPLACED-COUNT                  PIC 9(01) VALUE 0.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-RTN.
    MOVE "LOYD"       TO BANK-CODE.
    PERFORM
      VARYING LETTER-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
      UNTIL (LETTER-INDEX > 36) OR (REPLACED-COUNT = 4)
      PERFORM
        VARYING BANK-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL (BANK-INDEX > 4) OR (REPLACED-COUNT = 4)

      IF BANK-CODE-CHARACTER(BANK-INDEX) = LETTER-CHARACTER(LETTER-INDEX)
        SUBTRACT 1 
          FROM LETTER-INDEX 
                        GIVING BANK-CODE-NUMBER(BANK-INDEX)
        ADD 1               TO REPLACED-COUNT
      END-IF
      END-PERFORM
    END-PERFORM.

    DISPLAY BANK-CODE "-->" BANK-CODE-CONVERTED.
    ACCEPT BANK-CODE.
    STOP RUN.
```

Nothing particularly complex. Simple matter of redeclaration.

Comment: My apologies if my question is stupid, but how does this solve the problem of the bank code being possibly longer than 4 characters? I used LOYD as an example, but the program will be dealing with and bank codes from allover the world, varying in length.

Comment: So - change the "4" in significant places like the "occurs" clauses and the program code to the length of the bank-code field. You used 4 - I used 4. It doesn't matter how long the field is, for instance if it contains 20 characters in all, including the number and all of these need to encoded in the same way, then just change those `4`s to `20`. One caution - if you have spaces or other characters that are not in `letter-string` then the corresponding positions in the `BANK-CODE-CONVERTED` field will not be changed. Can only work with the information you supply.